# run the tutorial 3 gstreamer in the version gstreamer-1.0-android-arm 1.6.1 - not finding gstreamer-interfaces-0.10

Tags: android, gstreamer, java-gstreamer

I'm trying to run the tutorial 3 gstreamer in the version gstreamer-1.0-android-arm 1.6.1, but I'm not finding gstreamer-interfaces-0.10, how do I run tutorial3 with version 1.6.1?

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to newer version of tutorials here:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials/android-tutorial-3

I think there is no gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 in dependencies in [Android.mk](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials/android-tutorial-3/jni/Android.mk)

Not tested - based on [this mail](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-android/2014-June/000905.html)

HTH